# Instantiate is spawning more enemies than it should (it spawns 2)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

my script is spawning more enemies than it should, it's currently spawning 2 enemies instead of 1.
the difficulty is set by my script PlayerMovement and it's a integer between 1 and 3 including them.

Here is the script:

```
public class enemyspawner : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject enemyeasy;
public GameObject enemyhard;
public GameObject enemyinsane;
public int timer;
public float time;
public int howmuchenemies = 1;
public PlayerMovement pm;
private int difficulty;

public void Start()
{
    difficulty = pm.difficult;
    time = timer;
}
public void Update()
{
    time = time - Time.deltaTime;
    if (time <= 0 && howmuchenemies >= 0)
    {
        if (difficulty == 1)
        {
            Invoke("spawneasy", 0.0005f);

        }
        if (difficulty ==2)
        {
            Invoke("spawnhard", 0.0005f);
        }
        if (difficulty == 3)
        {
            Invoke("spawninsane", 0.0005f);
        }
    }
}
public void spawneasy()
{
    Instantiate(enemyeasy, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    howmuchenemies = howmuchenemies - 1;
}
public void spawnhard()
{
    howmuchenemies = howmuchenemies - 1;
    Instantiate(enemyhard, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    
}
public void spawninsane()
{
    Instantiate(enemyinsane, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    howmuchenemies =howmuchenemies - 1;
}
```

}

Comment: Since it's a `public int`, it will be serialized in the unity editor, and that value will overwrite your `= 1` with whatever you've written there, so please verify that the component in the unity inspector also has `1` on `howmuchenemies`.

Comment: Oh sorry, just noticed that you have `=> 0`, meaning you want to spawn enemies when the value is _more or equal to zero_, meaning you spawn when `howmuchenemies` is 1 and you spawn when `howmuchenemies` is 0. But stop when it's `-1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using

```
howmuchenemies >= 0
```

So in your case this will be true for `1` **and `0`**!

You probably want to change this to

```
howmuchenemies > 0
```

---

Btw you can just write

```
howmuchenemies--;
```

which is a bit more convinient ;)

And personally I would also suggest the following changes

```
// instead of "magic" int values I would use an enum
// This is less error prone and you can give your values meaningfull names
public enum Difficulty
{
    // You might then consider to rather remove the value assignments
    // and let it start by 0
    Easy = 1,
    Hard = 2,
    Insane = 3
}

// Then use the enum as type everywhere instead of int
// Of course have to use the same type also in your PlayerMove script
private Difficulty difficulty;

// in general use constants where possible
// This a) is slightly faster and b) this way you have a single point of maintenance
private const float SPAWNDELAY = 0.0005f;

// Update is called each frame by the Unity engine itself
// I wouldn't make it "public" as usually you should not call this from the outside
private void Update()
{
    // I would make the counter check first so you can save a little bit of work
    if(howmuchenemies <= 0) return;

    // shorter way to write 2time = time - Time.deltaTime"
    time -= Time.deltaTime;
    if (time <= 0)
    {
        // In general instead of many "if-else" blocks checking always the same variable / field
        // you rather want to use "switch-case" which works like a Hashmap and is therefor way more efficient
        switch(difficulty)
        {
            case Difficulty.Easy:
                // IF you use string based method at least use "nameof"
                // This way if you ever rename the method you do not need to also make this change in every place where you used the name
                Invoke(nameof(spawneasy), SPAWNDELAY);
                break;

            case Difficulty.Hard:
                Invoke(nameof(spawnhard), SPAWNDELAY);
                break;

            case Difficulty.Insane:
                Invoke(nameof(spawninsane), SPAWNDELAY);
                break;

            // always add a default case
            // This way if you later decide to add more Difficulty levels
            // you don't forget that easy to also implemented the needed method for it
            // so instead of simply nothing happening you get a clear exception at exactly the point where you need it
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

---

And then one more point: Currently as soon as the `time <= 0` is reached it will spawn **one enemy each frame** until `howmuchenemies <= 0`. I guess you would either want

All enemies are spawned at once

```
private void Update()
{
    if(howmuchenemies <= 0) return;

    time -= Time.deltaTime;
    if (time <= 0)
    {
        // loop until all enemies are spawned at once
        while(howmuchenemies > 0)
        {
            switch(difficulty)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or what I guess is the case here you rather want to restart the timer after each spawn and do

```
private void Update()
{
    if(howmuchenemies <= 0) return;

    time -= Time.deltaTime;
    if (time <= 0)
    {
        switch(difficulty)
        {
            ...
        }

        // reset the timer
        time = timer;
    }
}
```